# Clear all TextViews in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have much, about 20 TextViews in my Fragment.

**I want to setText empty or default status** in all Views by button.

**What is the simpy way to do that ?**

Currently I use setText/text on my View and put empty string, but for 20 TextView is 20 line... too much.

Is there method for clear all state or return to default status of Views in Fragment ?

```
myTextView1.text = ""
myTextView2.text = ""
myTextView3.text = ""
myTextView4.text = ""
myTextView5.text = ""
```

and much more

Comment: post code regarding your situation.

Comment: done, check now

Comment: you can destroy the fragment and create it again, but unless i see your code and the context of your application, then i don't know for sure. you can save your textviews in a container, then use listener for button event, inside the event traverse the container and set each back to null.

Comment: Depending on what kind of viewgroup they are in, you could do a for loop on it's children to set text to blank

Answer (score 1):

You can grab all the textViews within your parent view by using:

```
root.children.forEach { 
            if (it is TextView){
                it.text = ""
            }
        }
```

where `root` is the id of your container for all the textViews

Answer (score 0):

Declare this in your activity:

```
var textViews: ArrayList<TextView> = arrayListOf()
```

and in onCreate():

```
for (i in 1..20) {
    textViews.add(findViewById<TextView>(resources.getIdentifier("myTextView" + i, "id", this.getPackageName())))
}
```

when you want to clear them:

```
textViews.forEach { it.text = "" }
```